# How can I see if apache is overloaded and dropping or not accepting connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, tuning

Basically I just want to see if apache is handling a current level of high traffic or if I need to tune it to handle more connections. (I have found plenty of information on the actual tuning, so no help needed there)

I know it has been dropping or not accepting connections earlier today, but not seeing anything in the error logs.

- Is the expected behavior to throw a 503 in the error log if apache cannot accept more connections?
- If so, what error logging level do I need in order to see these?
- What is the correct terminology: dropping connections or not accepting connections?

MPM is prefork, OS is Linux, apache version is 2.2.15.

Answer (score 3):

You could use mod_status and look at the scoreboard.
If the board is full, you might want to investigate increasing the number of workers.

Answer (score 0):

Apache will 503 if it is getting too many connections.  It should only do this if your server's processor gets maxed out.  You can see if this is happening with the "top" command or "htop" for more detail.

Allowing more apache workers to spawn should help alleviate the load a bit.